# Is there a way to know if a commit date was modified?

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, git-commit

I'm doing classes in a university course and one of the tools we teach and use is VCS, GitHub to be precise.
So, for the students to learn how to use Git and for us to be able to track a student's progress we make them submit their homeworks via GitHub and that's been working very well for the last semesters.

The problem with doing things as explained before is that one can relatively easy modify the commit timestamp, so if a student wanted to they could change the last commit date to be before the deadline even if it was done after.
For now we trust that the students won't do that, but I would like to know if there's a way to know if the timestamp was modified, just in case.

Comment: You could fetch everything on the due date. In the future you could to do a git fetch --dry-run. If you see a force update. You know they rewrote history.

Comment: Taking a snapshot exactly at the time of the deadline is probably the best idea. It only needs read access to the repository and is impossible to fool (except by actually doing the work on time, but which student will do that?)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I'm not familiar with --dry-run, what does it do?

Comment: It does the fetch without making changes. It will look like it got the updates but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know if a commit date in git was modified, but on GitHub specifically, you can set up a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to the repository(ies) in question to post a message to a server you know cannot be modified by the students whenever a commit is made. This way, the real date and time of the commit will be recorded.